Migrating a VM from AWS to GCP
We have plan to migrate a windows VM running on AWS to GCP. I have a few questions regarding this migration.
Will the credentials used for logging into the AWS machine work for the migrated GCP machine as well ?
Will the softwares need to be re-installed on the migrated GCP machine ?
Is there any checklist for activities that need to be done on GCP after the machine is migrated ?


The user and password or ssh key to login will be unchanged. The machine should work the same in GCP as AWS, though it may need to have things like software repos updated.
